# Wordpress thumbnail image stretch

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have attached a thumbnail image to the post. I have used the following code

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
  add_image_size( 'post-image', 550, 650, true );
}
```

This is the site URL http://digitalsensebd.com/talking-threads/ .But images go to stretch when the height more than 650px. Please tell me how can I solve the stretch problem.

Comment: No need for `function_exists`. It is a build in function in the core. Also do not see the reason for this being backwards compatibility

Comment: Btw, I think that your image size problem has got to do with the content width set in your theme

Answer (score 0):

In `main.css` line 127, you have the CSS `.thumblin-img img { width: 100%; }`. If you change that property, or remove it, you will see your picture not stretch.

Comment: but i need the width of image 100% of the div

Comment: Is any way to make with 100% wighout css? is it possible to write it here `add_image_size( 'post-image', 550, 650, true );`?

Comment: If you want to make the image 100% and maintain the perspective, use `height: auto` with it. So for instance, you could use this: `.thumblin-img img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` and your image will stretch to the max width of the container, and maintain it's perspective.

Comment: but it takes too much hight. I need 650px height and 100% width

Comment: I believe you are looking for this `add_image_size( 'wide-image-icon', 9999, 650, false );`. See this thread:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24202/the-post-thumbnail-custom-sizes-not-display-correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the aspect ratio (and make the site responsive) change the CSS to this:

```
.thumblin-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you're using the featured image you might want to use "set_post_thumbnail_size" instead of "add_image_size":

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 550, 650, true );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size